# Kotlin: how to pass a sequence (coroutine) as Iterable<T>

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I don't understand how to pass a Coroutine where an Iterable is needed.

Assume I have the following function:

```
fun <T> iterate(iterable: Iterable<T>) {
    for (obj in iterable) {
        // do something..
    }
}
```

I want to pass a coroutine:

```
iterate( ?? {
    for (obj in objects) {
        yield(transform(obj))
    }
})
```

What am I supposed to put instead of the `??` for this to work? I tried `buildIterator` and `buildSequence` but neither one of them work.

Comment: Casting `buildSequence{...}.asIterable()` should be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`asIterable()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/as-iterable.html):

```
val seq = buildSequence {
    for (i in 1..5) {
        yield(i)
    }
}.asIterable()

iterate(seq)
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I don't understand why there isn't a `buildIterable` in the standard lib.. I've added it to my utils as `buildSequence(builderAction).asIterable()`

Comment: @AmirAbiri There's an `iterator` function.  https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/iterator.html